# Antimatter structures and chirality

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, antimatter, molecules, chirality

I'm curious whether the reversal of spin number in antiparticles vis-a-vis their matter counterparts would have a corresponding reversal of the chirality of structures made of antimatter (over scales where gravity is insignificant). For instance, natural glucose is right-handed; if we assembled a perfect antimatter copy of a natural glucose molecule in some futuristic laboratory, would it have left-handed configuration? If I could somehow manufacture and contain an antimatter version of this text, would I need a mirror to read it?

Comment: If you manufactured an antimatter copy of this text you could choose the directions text flows in.  It's an arbitrary choice.